# Netflix using native html5 in chrome--why no HD?

Tags: google-chrome, netflix, html5

So I'm using chrome to watch netflix now finally native without wine, and I can't seem to watch anything in HD.

My `chrome://gpu` looks good, everything plays fine in netflix in SD but nothing in HD.
The option in settings for preferring the html5 player does not show up. The netflix support says that in chrome it's not supposed to because html5 is a part of chrome.
EDIT: To be more specific, nothing plays higher than a resolution of 480... no 720p content is working at 720p.  The frustration resulted in me going back to windows... dare I admit it on here.  I would love to put Ubuntu back on my HTPC if I can get this issue resolved on my other machine.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix does currently not support a higher resolution than 720p with Chrome and HTML5:

https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742

Comment: 720p is also HD

Comment: The 720p resolution is what is not playing.  I get nothing in HD, nothing higher than 480